# Parsing Java with Antlr, error: extraneous input 'import' expecting {...}

Tags: java, antlr

I am trying to use Antlr-maven-plugin @ 4.7.2 to parse some Java source code on my ubuntu22.04. I used the g4 files from [Here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/java/java8) and successfully generated the Parser and Lexer. The main function is as follows:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(
        "/xxx/java-antler-parser/src/main/java/Test.java"));
    Java8Lexer lexer = new Java8Lexer(CharStreams.fromStream(inputStream));
    Java8Parser parser = new Java8Parser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    System.out.println(parser.expression());
  }
```

The test file is just a java file with regular import and basic logic. Showing part of the file as follows:

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.Lexer;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ParserRuleContext;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.PredictionMode;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.System;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException;
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;

class Test {
  //    public static long lexerTime = 0;
  public static boolean profile = false;
  public static boolean notree = false;
  public static boolean gui = false;
  public static boolean printTree = false;
...
```

However, there was no output except one error message:

```
line 1:0 extraneous input 'import' expecting {'boolean', 'byte', 'char', 'double', 'float', 'int', 'long', 'new', 'short', 'super', 'this', 'void', IntegerLiteral, FloatingPointLiteral, BooleanLiteral, CharacterLiteral, StringLiteral, 'null', '(', '!', '~', '++', '--', '+', '-', Identifier, '@'}
[]
```

The "expecting" list is far less than that defined in the g4 file. Meanwhile, when I searched the word "import" in the Parser, I could see tons of definitions including "import".

What I want is a parser that could provide me with the tokens' type and index such as
`[@0,0:5='import',<IMPORT>,1:0],[@1,6:6=' ',<WHITESPACE>1:6], [@2,7:9='org',<Identifier>1:9]...`
What should I do?

Comment: Please show the (beginning of) the input file.

Comment: To be sure, there is no package declaration in the input file?

Comment: @Seabass I randomly picked a java source code file as the input file. If you mean `import xxx.xx.xx`, then yes. Pls tell me if I misunderstood you :D

Comment: @lidaZHAO, No, I meant java class files should start with a package declaration unless it uses the default package. But never mind, as Bart Kiers describes its irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> ...
> System.out.println(parser.expression());
> ```

If you're trying to parse the input using the `expression` production, then it won't work (because the input isn't an expression). Use the `compilationUnit` production instead:

```java
String source = "import org.antlr.v4.runtime.Lexer;\n" +
    "import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ParserRuleContext;\n" +
    "import org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.PredictionMode;\n" +
    "\n" +
    "import java.io.File;\n" +
    "import java.lang.System;\n" +
    "import java.util.ArrayList;\n" +
    "import java.util.List;\n" +
    "import java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException;\n" +
    "import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;\n" +
    "\n" +
    "class Test {\n" +
    "  // public static long lexerTime = 0;\n" +
    "  public static boolean profile = false;\n" +
    "  public static boolean notree = false;\n" +
    "  public static boolean gui = false;\n" +
    "  public static boolean printTree = false;\n" +
    "}";

Java8Lexer lexer = new Java8Lexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));
Java8Parser parser = new Java8Parser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
ParseTree root = parser.compilationUnit();
System.out.println(root.toStringTree(parser));

// If `compilationUnit` didn't produce any errors, you know the file is
// syntactically correct, now just dump the tokens to the STDOUT
lexer.reset();
CommonTokenStream commonTokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
commonTokenStream.fill();

for (Token t : commonTokenStream.getTokens()) {
    System.out.printf(
        "type=%-25s text='%s'%n",
        Java8Lexer.VOCABULARY.getSymbolicName(t.getType()),
        t.getText()
    );
}
```

which produces:

```
(compilationUnit (importDeclaration (singleTypeImportDeclaration import (typeName (packageOrTypeName (packageOrTypeName (packageOrTypeName (packageOrTypeName org) . antlr) . v4) . runtime) . Lexer) ;)) (importDeclaration (singleTypeImportDeclaration import (typeName (packageOrTypeName (packageOrTypeName (packageOrTypeName (packageOrTypeName org) . antlr) . v4) . runtime) . ParserRuleContext) ;)) (importDeclaration (singleTypeImportDeclaration import (typeName (packageOrTypeName (packageOrTypeName (packageOrTypeName (packageOrTypeName (packageOrTypeName org) . antlr) . v4) . runtime) . atn) . PredictionMode) ;)) (importDeclaration (singleTypeImportDeclaration import (typeName (packageOrTypeName (packageOrTypeName java) . io) . File) ;)) (importDeclaration (singleTypeImportDeclaration import (typeName (packageOrTypeName (packageOrTypeName java) . lang) . System) ;)) (importDeclaration (singleTypeImportDeclaration import (typeName (packageOrTypeName (packageOrTypeName java) . util) . ArrayList) ;)) (importDeclaration (singleTypeImportDeclaration import (typeName (packageOrTypeName (packageOrTypeName java) . util) . List) ;)) (importDeclaration (singleTypeImportDeclaration import (typeName (packageOrTypeName (packageOrTypeName (packageOrTypeName java) . util) . concurrent) . BrokenBarrierException) ;)) (importDeclaration (singleTypeImportDeclaration import (typeName (packageOrTypeName (packageOrTypeName (packageOrTypeName java) . util) . concurrent) . CyclicBarrier) ;)) (typeDeclaration (classDeclaration (normalClassDeclaration class Test (classBody { (classBodyDeclaration (classMemberDeclaration (fieldDeclaration (fieldModifier public) (fieldModifier static) (unannType (unannPrimitiveType boolean)) (variableDeclaratorList (variableDeclarator (variableDeclaratorId profile) = (variableInitializer (expression (assignmentExpression (conditionalExpression (conditionalOrExpression (conditionalAndExpression (inclusiveOrExpression (exclusiveOrExpression (andExpression (equalityExpression (relationalExpression (shiftExpression (additiveExpression (multiplicativeExpression (unaryExpression (unaryExpressionNotPlusMinus (postfixExpression (primary (primaryNoNewArray_lfno_primary (literal false)))))))))))))))))))))) ;))) (classBodyDeclaration (classMemberDeclaration (fieldDeclaration (fieldModifier public) (fieldModifier static) (unannType (unannPrimitiveType boolean)) (variableDeclaratorList (variableDeclarator (variableDeclaratorId notree) = (variableInitializer (expression (assignmentExpression (conditionalExpression (conditionalOrExpression (conditionalAndExpression (inclusiveOrExpression (exclusiveOrExpression (andExpression (equalityExpression (relationalExpression (shiftExpression (additiveExpression (multiplicativeExpression (unaryExpression (unaryExpressionNotPlusMinus (postfixExpression (primary (primaryNoNewArray_lfno_primary (literal false)))))))))))))))))))))) ;))) (classBodyDeclaration (classMemberDeclaration (fieldDeclaration (fieldModifier public) (fieldModifier static) (unannType (unannPrimitiveType boolean)) (variableDeclaratorList (variableDeclarator (variableDeclaratorId gui) = (variableInitializer (expression (assignmentExpression (conditionalExpression (conditionalOrExpression (conditionalAndExpression (inclusiveOrExpression (exclusiveOrExpression (andExpression (equalityExpression (relationalExpression (shiftExpression (additiveExpression (multiplicativeExpression (unaryExpression (unaryExpressionNotPlusMinus (postfixExpression (primary (primaryNoNewArray_lfno_primary (literal false)))))))))))))))))))))) ;))) (classBodyDeclaration (classMemberDeclaration (fieldDeclaration (fieldModifier public) (fieldModifier static) (unannType (unannPrimitiveType boolean)) (variableDeclaratorList (variableDeclarator (variableDeclaratorId printTree) = (variableInitializer (expression (assignmentExpression (conditionalExpression (conditionalOrExpression (conditionalAndExpression (inclusiveOrExpression (exclusiveOrExpression (andExpression (equalityExpression (relationalExpression (shiftExpression (additiveExpression (multiplicativeExpression (unaryExpression (unaryExpressionNotPlusMinus (postfixExpression (primary (primaryNoNewArray_lfno_primary (literal false)))))))))))))))))))))) ;))) })))) <EOF>)
type=IMPORT                    text='import'
type=Identifier                text='org'
type=DOT                       text='.'
type=Identifier                text='antlr'
type=DOT                       text='.'
type=Identifier                text='v4'
type=DOT                       text='.'
type=Identifier                text='runtime'
type=DOT                       text='.'
type=Identifier                text='Lexer'
type=SEMI                      text=';'
type=IMPORT                    text='import'
type=Identifier                text='org'
type=DOT                       text='.'
type=Identifier                text='antlr'
type=DOT                       text='.'
type=Identifier                text='v4'
type=DOT                       text='.'
type=Identifier                text='runtime'
type=DOT                       text='.'
type=Identifier                text='ParserRuleContext'
type=SEMI                      text=';'
type=IMPORT                    text='import'
type=Identifier                text='org'
type=DOT                       text='.'
type=Identifier                text='antlr'
type=DOT                       text='.'
type=Identifier                text='v4'
type=DOT                       text='.'
type=Identifier                text='runtime'
type=DOT                       text='.'
type=Identifier                text='atn'
type=DOT                       text='.'
type=Identifier                text='PredictionMode'
type=SEMI                      text=';'
type=IMPORT                    text='import'
type=Identifier                text='java'
type=DOT                       text='.'
type=Identifier                text='io'
type=DOT                       text='.'
type=Identifier                text='File'
type=SEMI                      text=';'
type=IMPORT                    text='import'
type=Identifier                text='java'
type=DOT                       text='.'
type=Identifier                text='lang'
type=DOT                       text='.'
type=Identifier                text='System'
type=SEMI                      text=';'
type=IMPORT                    text='import'
type=Identifier                text='java'
type=DOT                       text='.'
type=Identifier                text='util'
type=DOT                       text='.'
type=Identifier                text='ArrayList'
type=SEMI                      text=';'
type=IMPORT                    text='import'
type=Identifier                text='java'
type=DOT                       text='.'
type=Identifier                text='util'
type=DOT                       text='.'
type=Identifier                text='List'
type=SEMI                      text=';'
type=IMPORT                    text='import'
type=Identifier                text='java'
type=DOT                       text='.'
type=Identifier                text='util'
type=DOT                       text='.'
type=Identifier                text='concurrent'
type=DOT                       text='.'
type=Identifier                text='BrokenBarrierException'
type=SEMI                      text=';'
type=IMPORT                    text='import'
type=Identifier                text='java'
type=DOT                       text='.'
type=Identifier                text='util'
type=DOT                       text='.'
type=Identifier                text='concurrent'
type=DOT                       text='.'
type=Identifier                text='CyclicBarrier'
type=SEMI                      text=';'
type=CLASS                     text='class'
type=Identifier                text='Test'
type=LBRACE                    text='{'
type=PUBLIC                    text='public'
type=STATIC                    text='static'
type=BOOLEAN                   text='boolean'
type=Identifier                text='profile'
type=ASSIGN                    text='='
type=BooleanLiteral            text='false'
type=SEMI                      text=';'
type=PUBLIC                    text='public'
type=STATIC                    text='static'
type=BOOLEAN                   text='boolean'
type=Identifier                text='notree'
type=ASSIGN                    text='='
type=BooleanLiteral            text='false'
type=SEMI                      text=';'
type=PUBLIC                    text='public'
type=STATIC                    text='static'
type=BOOLEAN                   text='boolean'
type=Identifier                text='gui'
type=ASSIGN                    text='='
type=BooleanLiteral            text='false'
type=SEMI                      text=';'
type=PUBLIC                    text='public'
type=STATIC                    text='static'
type=BOOLEAN                   text='boolean'
type=Identifier                text='printTree'
type=ASSIGN                    text='='
type=BooleanLiteral            text='false'
type=SEMI                      text=';'
type=RBRACE                    text='}'
type=EOF                       text='<EOF>'
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. However, the result does not look like what I wanted. I want something to provide me with each token's type and position.  example 
```
[@0,0:3='john',<WORD>,1:0]
[@1,4:4=' ',<WHITESPACE>,1:4]
[@2,5:8='SAYS',<SAYS>,1:5]
```

Comment: @lidaZHAO I updated my answer. Of course, you will not get any `WORD` or `SAYS` tokens because those are not present in the Java lexer.

Comment: Your code is awesome, thanks again! For the `WORD` or `SAYS` problem, I guess that is a bad example. What I wanted is the position (or say index) of tokens. For example: [@0,0:5='import',<IMPORT>,1:0],[@1,6:6=' ',<WHITESPACE>1:6]. But never mind, I find it in the Token class. Problem solved, thanks again!